# va_list has not been declared

Tags: gcc, g++, compiler-errors, variadic-functions

When compiling some working code on Fedora 11, I am getting this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4.1/cstdarg:56: error: ‘::va_list’ has not been declared
```

I am using:

```
[doriad@davedesktop VTK]$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2)
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: We have a `telepath-needed` tag?

Comment: @Maulrus: Not any more we don't. (It'd be implicit in almost every low-scoring question asked if we had it for real…)

Comment: Hi David

I ran into the same issue on Ubuntu 9.10. Using GCC 4.4.1

Did you resolve this? If yes please help me out.

Thanks
Vinit

Comment: Still not resolved, even if i use stdarg.h.

Error just changes to 
va_list not declared in scope

Answer (score 48):

I had the same error message and I solved including one of the next files

```
#include <stdarg.h>
```

or

```
#include <cstdarg>
```

Answer (score 4):

Bringing in the varadic macro set  in g++ 4.4 has confusing and twisted semantics. You might get a better idea of what isn't happening by using `g++ -E broken_code.cpp` and looking at what the pre-processor is bringing in. There are a few dozen GNU C preprocessor directives that could prevent the `::va_list` declaration from compiling as `__gnuc_va_list` which itself is of type `__builtin_va_list`

The junk code:

```
$cat junk.cpp
#include <cstdarg>

void foo(char *f, ...) { va_list va; va_start(va, va); }
int main(void) { foo("", "", ""); return 0; }
$ g++ junk.cpp
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) 4.4.1
```

compiles and links (with warnings) with the relevant output of `g++ -E junk.cpp` being:

```
# 40 "/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/include/stdarg.h" 3 4
typedef __builtin_va_list __gnuc_va_list;
# 102 "/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/include/stdarg.h" 3 4
typedef __gnuc_va_list va_list;
# 45 "/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstdarg" 2 3
# 54 "/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstdarg" 3
namespace std __attribute__ ((__visibility__ ("default"))) {

  using ::va_list;

}
```