# Gearman on Cygwin: 'va_list' has not been declared

Tags: c++, cygwin, gearman

I'm installing Gearman 1.1.12 on Windows 8.1 through Cygwin and getting the following error:

```
  CXX      libtest/libtest_libtest_la-formatter.lo
In file included from ./libtest/test.hpp:69:0,
                 from ./libtest/common.h:85,
                 from libtest/formatter.cc:39:
./libtest/exception.hpp:83:13: error: 'va_list' has not been declared
    void init(va_list);
              ^
```

I've verified that the source code has the necessary includes and that the GCC/G++ compilers are the latest version, 4.8.2

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Which do you consider is the relevant include, and how did you make sure it was included in time?

Comment: Gearman on Windows with Cygwin sounds dirty.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364358/va-list-has-not-been-declared

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've looked at the source code and where the va_list is used and the stdarg.h or cstarg include is set appropriately IMO.

Comment: Al I've seen this, it didn't help.

Comment: Create the preprocessor output (`g++ -E` plus your other compilation options) and scrutinize that (`g++ -E ... yourfile.cpp | tee yourfile.E | grep va_list`).  You should see a `typedef __gnuc_va_list va_list;` line.  If you don't, you should look really hard at the `yourfile.E` output and see what's going on. You might find the `-H` option useful too; it lists the headers that are included.  I expect the answer will be in there, somewhere.

Comment: If you include a C++ standard header, it *may or may not* bring in other standard headers. Apparently the gearman source implicitly depends on this kind of accidental inclusion. Ideally, each file that refers to a symbol should explicitly `#include` the header that defines that symbol. Gearman doesn't follow this convention; `libtest/exception.hpp` refers to `size_t` (defined in `<cstddef>` or `<stddef.h>`) and `va_arg` (defined in `<cstdarg>` and `<stdarg.h>`), and it has *no* `#include` directives at all. Apparently it depends on files that `#include` it to `#include` the necessary headers.

Comment: I suggest submitting a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/gearmand

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today and it was "fixed" by including `<cstdarg>` on libtest/test.hpp.

Did you check that?

(Wanted to reply as a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet)

Comment: That was it. Good job!